# Word for an Original Idea

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, formality

Is there a good word for an idea that someone came up with on their own?  I'm talking about an original idea.  The reason I want such a word is for my notes so that I can annotate, with as few words as possible, whether I reached an idea on my own or whether I used someone else's. I prefer a formal term over informal.

Comment: What is wrong with "original idea"?

Comment: @MattЭллен Nothing. I just want to know if there is a single word I can use that conveys the same message.

Comment: @Matt: The only thing wrong with that is that there is no such thing.

Comment: The choice might be guided by context. I can envision situations where setting “invention” contrary to “collaboration” (or perhaps “addendum”) would be sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider ***brainchild***. It is an informal word.

> An idea or invention considered to be a particular person’s creation:
>
> *the statue is the brainchild of a local landscape artist*
>
> <sup>http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/brainchild</sup>
>
> ---
>
> An original idea or plan attributed to a person or group.
>
> <sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brainchild</sup>

You can consider ***inspiration*** as a more formal word.

> a product of your creative thinking and work; *"he had little respect for the inspirations of other artists"*
>
> Something, such as a sudden creative act or idea, that is inspired.
>
> <sup>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inspiration</sup>

Comment: Except for it being informal, I think this is almost exactly the type of word I'm looking for.

Comment: @AlexW: Updated my answer with a more formal word.

Comment: I don’t think of “brainchild” as informal.

Answer (score 2):

How about [epiphany](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/epiphany) [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary]:

> 3. a sudden, intuitive perception of or insight into reality or the essential meaning of something, often initiated by some simple, commonplace occurrence.
> 4. a literary work or section of a work presenting such a moment of revelation and insight.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a [brainstorm](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Brainstorm):

> - a sudden inspiration or idea.
> - A sudden clever plan or idea.

for a more formal but less common term, [intellection](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Intellection):

> - mental activity; thought
> - an idea or thought

- notebooks filled with his intellections on an amazing array of topics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do think that works, but I don't like how it is an informal definition. I've edited my question to ask for formality.

Answer (score 0):

Two words come to mind, namely: {Inventive or contrivance}. The latter is defined as "Act or faculty of contriving; maneuvering; invention or inventive ability." Inventive is compared to 'original'.